# Use cases of indirect recursion

Tags: c, algorithm, recursion, analysis

While learning direct and indirect recursion by these examples:

***Example1***

```
int x(int);
int y(int);

int y(int b)
{
    return b*x(b-1);
}


int x(int a)
{
    if (a==0)
        return 1;
    else
        return y(a);
}

// int result = x(5)      =>   120
```

***Example2***

```
int n = 0;
void foo1(void);
void foo2(void);

void foo1() 
{ 
  if (n <= 20) 
  { 
    printf("%d ", n);  // prints n
    n++;           // increments n by 1
    foo2();       // calls foo2() 
  } 
  else
    return; 
} 


void foo2() 
{ 
  if (n <= 20) 
  { 
    printf("%d ", n);  // prints n
    n++;           // increments n by 1
    foo1();       // calls foo1()
  } 
  else
    return; 
} 
// foo1();       output: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
```

I noticed that I can easily merge them into one single function:

```
// example1 merged to a single function
int x(int a)
{
    if (a==0)
        return 1;
    else
        return a*x(a-1);
}


// example2 merged to a single function
void foo1() 
{ 
  if (n <= 20) 
  { 
    printf("%d ", n);  // prints n
    n++;           // increments n by 1
    foo1();       // calls itself
  } 
  else
    return; 
}
```

My question is if we can solve these coding problems with direct recursion, so why indirect recursion even exists? (If there is any type of problem that can be solved only ***/*** is easier to solve with indirect recursion can you provide it here)

Comment: Indirect recursion is almost always regarded as a severe bug. As for why (indirect) recursion exists... Back in the 1960s and 1970s new up-coming programming languages competed over having the most (useless) features. Programming was a brand new thing and nobody actually knew which features that would actually become useful over time. Lots of misguided features like recursion, goto, setjmp, variadic functions etc etc originate from that era.

Comment: @Lundin This supports my conclusion about indirect recursion. Can you post this comment as an answer? ( It would be great If you could enrich it with some facts/formality)

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you can implement recursive forms without recursion by dynamic programming. In that case, you do not worry about the stack size and it is regularly faster. Hence, the great point of recursive implementation is its more readability and ease of implementation. You can interpret the same reason between a recursive function and a twisted (or indirect) recursive function. Because you can sometimes find the definition of a problem based on an indirect recursion instead of a recursive function faster, although you can rewrite those two functions within one recursive function by spending time over the interpretation of how to do it.